# pgfplotstable: string replace when formatting with 'postproc cell content' does not work

Tags: formatting, pgfplotstable, highlighting

It seems, that `string replace={XXX}{replaced}` does not work, if I use  `postproc cell content/.style={...}`. 
What can I do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, header=true]{
A;     B
111; aaa
222; XXX
333; ccc
444; ddd
555; XXX
}{\mytable}

\begin{document}

\section{With postproc cell content -- works not}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
columns/B/.style={
string replace={XXX}{replaced}, 
postproc cell content/.style={
  @cell content={\cellcolor{pink}\textcolor{blue}{##1}}   },
},
]{\mytable}

\section{Without postproc cell content -- works}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
columns/B/.style={
string replace={XXX}{replaced}, 
},
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the string as part of `postproc cell content`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, header=true]{
A;     B
111; aaa
222; XXX
333; ccc
444; ddd
555; XXX
}{\mytable}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \strifeq \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{With postproc cell content -- works not}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
columns/B/.style={
string replace={XXX}{replaced}, 
postproc cell content/.style={
  @cell content={\cellcolor{pink}\textcolor{blue}{##1}}   },
},
]{\mytable}

\section{Without postproc cell content -- works}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
columns/B/.style={
string replace={XXX}{replaced}, 
},
]{\mytable}

\section{With postproc cell content -- works}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
columns/B/.style={
postproc cell content/.style={
  @cell
  content={\cellcolor{pink}\textcolor{blue}{\strifeq{##1}{XXX}{replaced}{##1}}}},
},
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this hack works. For theoretical interests it could be intresting, how to use pgfplotstable's function `string replace={XXX}{replaced}` anyway.

Comment: @cis I have no idea, I don't use `pgfplotstable` myself.